wolt_modal_sheet remove title part in Flutter
WoltModalSheet.show(
    context: context,
    pageListBuilder: (context) {
      return [
        WoltModalSheetPage(
          child: Container(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 5, 24),
            height: context.width + 100,
            width: context.width,
          ),
        ),
      ];
    },
    pageIndexNotifier: ValueNotifier(0),
    onModalDismissedWithBarrierTap: null,
    onModalDismissedWithDrag: null,
    decorator: null,
    modalTypeBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      final width = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
      if (width < 523) {
        return WoltModalType.bottomSheet();
      } else if (width < 800) {
        return WoltModalType.dialog();
      } else {
        return WoltModalType.sideSheet();
      }
    },
    transitionAnimationController: null,
    enableDrag: false,
    showDragHandle: true,
    useSafeArea: false,
  );

I have this part and I want to remove the top area?


use this parameter to hide top bar in WoltModalSheetPage
 WoltModalSheetPage(
     hasTopBarLayer: false,
     .....

